# EF6 CodeFirst - Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm trying to update-database and got this error. I've been wrestling with this for a while and can't quite figure out what's happening.

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Comments_dbo.Users_UserId' on table 'Comments' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Here is my **User** class:

```
public class User
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public UserType ProfileType { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Location { get; set; }
    public int? SessionTokenId { get; set; }

    public SessionToken SessionToken { get; set; }
    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my **Comment** class:

```
public class Comment
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Message { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime PostDate { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
    public Article Article { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried to add some:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>()
            .HasRequired(u => u.User)
            .WithMany()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

I think it's wrong, and I need to delete all user comments on user deleting.

But it gives no result. What I'm wrote wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you have one more dependency, for example it could be between Article and User and in this case you must apply your fix for this too.